# Executing the FOP command line as batch from Perl

Tags: perl, xslt, xsl-fo

I am converting XML to PDF using Apache. I am executing the FOP command line as batch file( since the input file will be vary) from Perl as like below:

**Creating Batch file:**

```
open (OUT2, '>', 'c:\test\fop-1.0\run.bat');        

print OUT2  "cd\\\ncd c:\\test\\fop-1\.0\\\n C:\\test\\fop-1\.0\\fop\.bat -c C:\\test\\fop-1\.0\\conf\\fop-config\.xml -xsl C:\\test\\fop-1\.0\\test.xsl -xml c:\test\document2.xml -pdf c:\test\document2.pdf";

close (OUT2);
```

Executing batch file using system command:

```
$cmd2 ="c:\\test\\fop-1.0\\test.bat";

system("$cmd2");
```

I am embedding the svg files in the fop. I am getting the output when I run batch file manually, but by executing from perl I am getting the following error:

```
org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.PreloaderSVG$Loader ge...
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
system "cmd","/c","c:\\test\\fop-1.0\\test.bat";
```